# Convert data to array, and find count based on filters

Tags: php, arrays, counting

I have data stored in a text file (This is a requirement), which I’ve turned into an array… 
Now I’m trying filter my results based on 2 variables $Start_Date & $End_Date
…then display only unique values with the count next to it.

Stats.txt

```
08/02/14 | Red | Wood
08/03/14 | Red | Steel
08/04/14 | Blue | Wood
08/05/14 | Red | Steel
08/05/14 | Red | Wood
08/05/14 | Red | Steel
08/05/14 | Blue | Steel
08/06/14 | Blue | Wood
```

What I have so far:

```
  $logfile = "stats.txt";
  $Start_Date = 08/04/14;
  $End_Date = 08/05/14;

  if (file_exists($logfile)) {

        $handle = fopen($logfile, "r");
        $log = fread($handle, filesize($logfile));
        fclose($handle);

  } else {
        die ("The log file doesn't exist!");
  }

  // Seperate each logline

  $log = explode("\n", trim($log));

  // Seperate each part in each logline
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($log); $i++) {
        $log[$i] = trim($log[$i]);
        $log[$i] = explode('|', $log[$i]);
  }
```

Desired Result: (based on $Start_Date = 08/04/14 and $End_Date = 08/05/14)

```
<h2>Date Count:</h2>
08/04/14 - 1
08/05/14 - 4

<h2>Color Count:</h2>
Red - 3
Blue - 2

<h2>Material Count:</h2>
Wood - 2
Steel - 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write the code like this

```
$log = "08/02/14 | Red | Wood
08/03/14 | Red | Steel
08/04/14 | Blue | Wood
08/05/14 | Red | Steel
08/05/14 | Red | Wood
08/05/14 | Red | Steel
08/05/14 | Blue | Steel
08/06/14 | Blue | Wood";

$log = explode("\n", trim($log));   
// Seperate each part in each logline
$dateFreq = array();
$colorFreq = array();
$MaterialFreq = array();
foreach ($log as $line) {
    $lineArr = explode("|", $line);
    $date = trim($lineArr[0]);
    $color = trim($lineArr[1]);
    $material = trim($lineArr[2]);
    if ($date >= '08/04/14' && $date <= '08/05/14') {  
        if (isset($dateFreq[$date])) {
            $dateFreq[$date] = $dateFreq[$date] + 1;
        } else {
            $dateFreq[$date] = 1;
        }
        if (isset($colorFreq[$color])) {
            $colorFreq[$color] = $colorFreq[$color] + 1;
        } else {
            $colorFreq[$color] = 1;
        }
        if (isset($MaterialFreq[$material])) {
            $MaterialFreq[$material] = $MaterialFreq[$material] + 1;
        } else {
            $MaterialFreq[$material] = 1;
        }
    }
}
echo "<h2>Date Count:</h2>\n";
foreach ($dateFreq as $date => $freq) {
    echo $date, " - ", $freq, "\n";
}

echo "<h2>Color Count:</h2>\n";
foreach ($colorFreq as $color => $freq) {
    echo $color, " - ", $freq, "\n";
}

echo "<h2>Material Count:</h2>\n";
foreach ($MaterialFreq as $material => $freq) {
    echo $material, " - ", $freq, "\n";
}
```